# Alloy widget in Titanium making app crash

Tags: widget, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have imported a pickerView widget inside the widgets folder, however when I call the widget from my index.js, it doesn't provide the widget instead it crashs my application. I have attached the image. What is wrong?

[image]

Here is the piece of code I'm using to call widget, when the button is clicked

```
Alloy.createWidget('danielhanold.pickerWidget', {
  id: 'mySingleColumn',
  outerView: $.win,
  hideNavBar: false,
  type: 'single-column',
  selectedValues: [20],
  pickerValues: [{10: 'Auburn', 20: 'Bald', 30: 'Black', 40: 'Blond', 50: 'Brown'}],
  onDone: function(e) {
    // Do something

  },
```

widget link: https://github.com/danielhanold/danielhanold.pickerwidget

Answer (score 1):

We're using the same widget for a project we're working on.

Make sure you have the following in your app/config.json:

```
"dependencies": {
 "danielhanold.pickerWidget": "*"
}
```